# Where can WordPress (self-installed) shortcodes be rendered?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I've looked around for this but can't seem to find a definite answer. I want to know where WordPress shortcodes are supported within the (self-hosted) platform - meaning where can I safely place shortcode content and expect it to be rendered? I know I can use them in post and page content, and some widgets that output something. But can I use them in other plugins (that also output something), and which widgets are supported? Do custom plugins need to have something enabled that allows them to render shortcode content?

[This page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode) says:

> By default, WordPress does not support shortcodes within Sidebar Widgets. It only expands the shortcodes within the content of a Post, Page, or custom post type.

... although I've gotten shortcodes to work in the arbitrary text widget, so that information doesn't seem accurate. It also suggests I install [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-in-sidebar-widgets/) that hasn't been updated in years.

Is there any clarification somewhere on this that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<?php do_shortcode('name_of_shortcode'); ?>
```

e.g `echo do_shortcode('[gallery autoplay=no]');`

and it will render this shortcode. You can place it in functions.php, header.php, footer.php.

**EDIT:**

If you want it to work in Text Widget, all you need is to add this line of code in functions.php file:

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking how to use shortcodes from a code standpoint, but specifically where (within the WordPress admin section) shortcodes are supported?